# ddSlick select on change submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I am using ddslick. Is it possible on change to submit form ?

My code:

```
<form method="post" class="town_form">
     <select name="town" id="select_town">
         <option value="83">Chicago</option>
         <option value="112">New York</option>
     </select>
</form>

<script>
    $('#select_town').ddslick({
        onSelected: function(selectedData){
            $('.town_form').submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```

But its not working ... any help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#select_town').dblclick(function() {
    onSelected: function(data){
        if (data.selectedIndex > 0) {
            $('form.town_form').submit();
        }
    } 
});
```